# PHP 7 : Warning: expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, php-7.3

I want to click on a link and convert the `$data` received in the link.
However, the following error was displayed. It worked fine with PHP 5.x.
Is there any way to do it?
`$data` needs to be a string, but it becomes an array.
Error

```
Warning: mb_convert_kana() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

MbConvertKanaExtension.php

```php
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // mb_convert_kana_option
        if (isset($options['mb_convert_kana_option'])) {
            $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) use ($options) {
                $data = $event->getData();

                //ErrorCode
                $data = mb_convert_kana($data, $options['mb_convert_kana_option'], 'UTF-8');
                $event->setData($data);
            });
        }
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'mb_convert_kana_option' => 'aKV',
        ));
    }
```

twig

```
<a href="{{ path('ahi_sp_admin_hq_article_index', {"q": {"articleType": "coordinate"}}) }}">
```

Result of `var_dump($data);`

```
array(1) { ["articleType"]=> string(9) "recommend" } NULL string(9) "recommend" string(0) "" NULL NULL NULL
```

Version
PHP v7.3.25

Comment: Just for the record, it hasn't "worked fine" in PHP 5, check [here](https://3v4l.org/sEltk). You've probably changed something else as well (at the very least, your error reporting settings).

Comment: @El_Vanja Thanks for your comment. Well, PHP7 just visualized the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `$event->getData()` returns an associative array.

Based on the dump you showed, if you just want to get the string value of the "articleType" property from it, then simply:

```
mb_convert_kana($data["articleType"], ...
```

Also, `mb_convert_kana` returns a string, so you probably want to put that back into the `$data` array rather than completely overwriting it. So..

```
$data["articleType"] = mb_convert_kana($data["articleType"], ...
```

is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried, but I got the error ```Warning: Illegal string offset'articleType'``` for the code ```mb_convert_kana```. Is there any improvement plan?

Comment: @scottie320 The code I provided doesn't throw that error. Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e52afee1604b8c8f60452227ed3d948c5fad8a53 . If you're having a problem then I'd sugest either a) you didn't implement my suggestion correctly, or b) `$data` doesn't actually contain `array(1) { ["articleType"]=> string(9) "recommend" }` as you showed in the question.

Comment: I see. In fact, I thought that it was not relevant, and there was a part that was not included in the result of ```var_dump```. Can you check it again?